# How to pass a ref to a dynamically loaded component

Tags: reactjs, ref, react-functional-component, loadable-component

I'd like to pass a ref to a dynamically loaded component. When the component's loaded with a regular import everything works as expected. When using a dynamic import the ref value is `undefined || { current: null }`.

I get the following the error message in the console:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. 
Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

I've attempted to use a `React.forwardRef` but have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

**Parent Component:** `Recaptcha.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import loadable from '@loadable/component';
import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha';

export type RecaptchaProps = {
  handleOnError: () => void;
  handleOnExpire: () => void;
  forwardedRef: React.MutableRefObject<ReCAPTCHA | null>;
  error: string | null;
  load: boolean;
};

const Recaptcha: React.FunctionComponent<RecaptchaProps> = ({
  handleOnError,
  handleOnExpire,
  error,
  forwardedRef,
  // load,
}) => {
  const RecaptchaPackage = loadable(
    () => import('components/Form/Recaptcha/RecaptchaPackage'),
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <RecaptchaPackage
        handleOnError={handleOnError}
        handleOnExpire={handleOnExpire}
        forwardedRef={forwardedRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Recaptcha);
```

**Dynamic Component:** `RecaptchaPackage.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha';

export type RecaptchaPackageProps = {
  handleOnError: () => void;
  handleOnExpire: () => void;
  forwardedRef: React.MutableRefObject<ReCAPTCHA | null>;
};

const RecaptchaPackage: React.FunctionComponent<RecaptchaPackageProps> = ({
  handleOnError,
  handleOnExpire,
  forwardedRef,
}) => {
  return process.env.GATSBY_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC ? (
    <ReCAPTCHA
      onErrored={handleOnError}
      onExpired={handleOnExpire}
      ref={forwardedRef}
      sitekey={process.env.GATSBY_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC}
      size="invisible"
    />
  ) : null;
};

export default React.memo(RecaptchaPackage);
```

Comment: According to the loadable docs, the loadable call should be done outside of the component, so would try that. And yeah `forwardRef` is used to pass a ref from child to parent so you're right, doesn't help here.

Comment: I tried moving the loadable function outside the component, however, it still gets the same result.

Comment: Besides the ref returning undefined the dynamically loaded component is  correctly loading the recaptcha script. Without a valid ref however I’m unable to execute any functions with it.

Comment: I had another look at your code and actually `forwardsRef` is the right choice, as you are passing the ReCAPTCHA ref upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to pass a ref of the ReCAPTCHA component (from 'react-google-recaptcha') up through two parent elements. For this you can make use of React's `forwardRef`.

Another thing to note is that the ref will not always be assigned a value on component mount, this is true when using with and without dynamic loading. So if you want to log the ref for testing, log in a `setTimeout` or some other event that is triggered later.

Your Recaptcha component would look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import loadable from "@loadable/component";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

export type RecaptchaProps = {
  handleOnError: () => void;
  handleOnExpire: () => void;
  error: string | null;
  load: boolean;
};

const RecaptchaPackage = loadable(() => import("./RecaptchaPackage"));

const Recaptcha: React.FunctionComponent<RecaptchaProps> = React.forwardRef(({
  handleOnError,
  handleOnExpire,
  error,
  // load,
}, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <RecaptchaPackage
        ref={ref}
        handleOnError={handleOnError}
        handleOnExpire={handleOnExpire}
      />
    </div>
  );
})

export default React.memo(Recaptcha);
```

And your RecaptchaPackage component would look like this:

```
import React from "react";

import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

export type RecaptchaPackageProps = {
  handleOnError?: () => void;
  handleOnExpire?: () => void;
};

const RecaptchaPackage: React.FunctionComponent<RecaptchaPackageProps> = React.forwardRef(({
  handleOnError,
  handleOnExpire
}, ref) => {
  return process.env.GATSBY_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC ? (
    <ReCAPTCHA
      ref={ref}
      onErrored={handleOnError}
      onExpired={handleOnExpire}
      sitekey={process.env.GATSBY_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC}
      size="invisible"
    />
  ) : null);
});

export default React.memo(RecaptchaPackage);
```

I've created a sandbox that validates that this should work: https://playcode.io/972680

Comment: Made the necessary changes to the project and all is working now. Thanks for explanation and the code example, very helpful!